# How to Scroll down to click a particular element using Appium as scrollTo is not working

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm trying to scroll down and click on some element in setting, but as scrollTo is not working I'm not able to proceed

```
package Test1;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
public class MobileFindJavaTest {
private AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;

@BeforeMethod
 @Test
public void setUp() throws Exception {
File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/slide/");
File app = new File(appDir, "ApiDemos-debug.apk");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","BECUPJTWGA7HAQQK");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5");

capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.settings");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".Settings");
driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), c         Capabilities);


    //driver.scrollTo("Views");
    TouchAction touchAction4 = new TouchAction(driver);
    touchAction4.press(30,40).moveTo(89,51).release();
    driver.performTouchAction(touchAction4);
    System.out.println("gaurav");
    driver.findElementByName("Feature").click();

}

}
```

driver.scrollTo is showing not supported , now how to scroll down and click because the element which i want to click is not there on the screen , we need to scroll for it

```
MobileElement radioGroup = (MobileElement) wd

            .findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()"

            + ".resourceId(\"com.android.settings:id/title\")).scrollIntoView("

            + "new UiSelector().text(\"Feature\"));");
            radioGroup.click();
```

i tried in this way also but it is not scrolling...the setting opens and that's it

Comment: You can use the UiScrollable class - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html

Comment: can you please elaborate how to use it i am quite new in this Appium...Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can scroll using below code snippet:

```
public void scroll() {
    Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int Startpoint = (int) (dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5);
    int scrollEnd = (int) (dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5);
    driver.swipe(200, Startpoint,200,scrollEnd,2000); 
}
```

You can have some condition upto which this method can be called and once your condition is met, scrolling will stop and you can perform desired action. Something like:

```
while(condition){
    scroll();
}
```

P.S.: You can modify value of 0.5 as required, I used the value as required in my case.

Comment: can you please explain how it is working, because i tried still it is not scrolling

Comment: replace the value 0.5 with 0.2 in syntax  int scrollEnd = (int) (dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5); and try again. It has always worked for me.

Comment: it didnt worked ...can you please explain how it actually works

Comment: It actually swipes the screen starting at 0.5 * height of screen to 0.2 (what so ever value you specify here) * height of screen

Comment: Abhinav, here I applied while loop for condition (!(element.isDisplayed())) , so when the said element is not displayed the scroll() function is called and should scroll the screen till webelement is find  but when we run the script the driver searches for element and doesn't able to find it & finally throws error. So screen scroll never happens.

Comment: In my case the screen is split into two section, where as one section is static and the another one is scrollable vertically. The current solution does not work, how can we try it

Answer (score 2):

// create a method name scrollTo or any name of your choice , with below mentioned code it will take parameter of text using which we want to scroll :

```
public void scrollTo(String text)
{                
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+text+"\").instance(0))");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Feature" text is display text or content description

if its display text :

```
MobileElement radioGroup = (MobileElement) wd

.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()"

+ ".resourceId(\"<listview_id>\")).scrollIntoView("

+ "new UiSelector().text(\"Feature\"));");
radioGroup.click();
```

This will scroll till the where the "Feature" text is displayed and click the "Feature" text. but one thing i need to explain you can scroll on only the view which has scroll functionality implemented not button, text etc..

if its content description :

```
wd.scrollToExact("Feature")
```

For more info, please check this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT3tqaLNn-Y

Click on Text:

```
MobileElement textLocartor = (MobileElement) wd

.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"<text_value>\")");

textLocartor.click();
```

Comment: one thing the resourceId is for the element which we need to click after scrolling rite?   what if it dosent have a resource id

Comment: most of the cases in single screen there will one major scroll view it could be listview, gridview, recycleview or nestedscrollview so you can get the class name instead scrolling view id you can use class name. but for clicking here i mention text you need to click on text , you can click which mentioned above.

Comment: my doubt is if i have only text value for an element which need to be clicked, then what could be done

Comment: if you want to click only text value means just click on text code snippet is refer above

Comment: `MobileElement radioGroup = (MobileElement) wd

          .findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()"

          + ".resourceId(\"com.android.settings:id/title\")).scrollIntoView("

          + "new UiSelector().text(\"Feature\"));");
          radioGroup.click();`
i tried in this way also but it is not scrolling...the setting opens and that's it

Comment: can you please suggest what could be wrong in my case

Comment: can you post your screenshot, so that i will get some idea and also please post your appium full log

Answer (score 0):

For `ScrollTo()` function the below method worked very well:

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("+ "new UiSelector().text(\"_input your text name here_\"));").click();
```

Please try using the above method & this should solve your problem with regards to `scrollTo()` function, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
 driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("+ "new UiSelector().text(\"_TAGS_\"));");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using wd driver for java script the following scroll method worked for me

```js
await driver.execute('mobile: scroll', {'direction': 'down'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the best one line solution I found for those people who are using Appium Java client version above 6--

```
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+text+"\").instance(0))"));
```

Comment: This is perfect solution, I'm currently using it 100% works.